# All MSTest Tests being ignored

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2013, mstest

I have a visual studio 2013 with resharper 8.1 installed.

Out of nowhere all the unittests started being ignored, with no stack message at all.

I´ve already, restarted VS, PC, and even uninstalled resharper.

Any thoughts?

Is there any log file available that could, at least, give me an extra hint?

TKS[image]

Comment: I take it you don't see the usual icons in the left gutter in the code editor too?  Captan Obvious asks: Are the classes and methods public?  Any change in "assembly friendship" lately?

Comment: Yes. There have been some changes, as the project evolved. but It´s kinda hard to determine what´s going on without any message. I have 30 tests, that used to run and now, they´re all being ignored. Is there any kind of logging, to tell me why they´re being ignored?

Comment: Tried also creating a new test project from scracth in the solution, and got the same behaviour

Comment: R# doesn't maintain a build-to-build state, so it can tell when tests "disappear" from its point of view.  (unless you've got a session window open and have been running tests periodically when R# decided they don't exist anymore).  Maybe try installing TestDriven.net to see if it recognizes them.  I assume you can run the tests fine right in the NUnit GUI/Console?

Comment: I´ve never runned them from the Nunit Console. Will try here. R# is finding out the tests, and running them, but they´re all being ignored.

Comment: Just tested here Peter, they run indeed from Nunit GUI.

Comment: Can you add a screen show showing the tests are run/ignored by R#?

Comment: Put a image here. My Apologies for the confusion. They´re MSTest, not NuniTests. Once again, is there any log file?

Comment: Do you have SetUp/TestInitialize methods that are private?

Comment: Nope.Also, if I create a new project, with a sinmple Assert.asserttrue(true) test, on that solution its also failing.  Haven´t test on a brand new solution yet.

Comment: I found out that this is something related to a deployment "action" that is configured inside a testsettings.file. Will take a look at it today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a duplicated file in a deployment folder. Don´t know how windows let 2 files with the same name at the same folder, but they were there.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with the same symptoms has been solved by updating `NUnit` project dependency NuGet package up to last stable version. (May be just reinstalling could solve the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue. Was caused by multiple MSTest versions in the same solution.